# Accidently deleted /usr/share/m17n/icons. How can I get it back?

Tags: icons

I deleted two unnecessary files in `/usr/share/m17n/icons` folder, then I was about to delete another two files located in `/usr/share/m17n` folder.

I did not notice that the icons are still selected while hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. Now, it is missing. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dpkg` with the `-S` flag to identify the package that installs icons in the path `/usr/share/m17n/icons`
It is used to install/manage individual packages, in this case to identify which is the package to reinstall.

From `man dpkg`:

```
NAME

       dpkg - package manager for Debian

SYNOPSIS

       dpkg [option...] action

[...]

DESCRIPTION

       dpkg is a tool to install, build, remove and manage Debian
       packages. The primary and more user-friendly front-end for dpkg
       is aptitude(1). dpkg itself is controlled entirely via command
       line parameters, which consist of exactly one action and zero or
       more options. The action-parameter tells dpkg what to do and
       options control the behavior of the action in some way.

       dpkg can also be used as a front-end to dpkg-deb(1) and
       dpkg-query(1). The list of supported actions can be found later
       on in the ACTIONS section. If any such action is encountered dpkg
       just runs dpkg-deb or dpkg-query with the parameters given to it,
       but no specific options are currently passed to them, to use any
       such option the back-ends need to be called directly.

[...]

-S, --search filename-search-pattern...
                  Search for a filename from installed packages.
```

Open a terminal and run `dpkg -S /usr/share/m17n/icons/` to see that the impacted package is `m17n-db`

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/m17n/icons/
m17n-db: /usr/share/m17n/icons
```

Therefore, it's enough that you run the command: `sudo apt --reinstall install m17n-db`